# How can I understand what characters an application support?

Tags: windows-7, windows, unicode, characters

I use ProShow application and it seems it doesn't support the whole unicode characters, for examples this character: À ( U+00C0 ) with font Arial, replace it with a question mark (?).
Didn't find anything in its documentation.

How can I understand which set of characters an application support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always paste a [unicode table](http://ascii-table.com/unicode-chars.php?p=0) into the app and see what turns up.

But according to a [forum topic](http://www.proshowenthusiasts.com/viewtopic.php?p=37935&sid=bcefda21739d89d64519f2ac3fa97c57#p37935), it basically can only take a very small subset of characters. If you want unicode, it seems you'll have to generate an image and implant it on instead.